# Get all consecutive DIVs with specific class

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpquery

There is HTML like

```
<h3>Specifications</h3>
<div class="row"> some text </div>
<div class="row"> some text 2 </div>
<div class="row"> some text 3 </div>
<div class="detail-anchor" id="pricing"></div>
<div class="row"> some text 4</div>
```

I am using PHP + phpQuery to scrape a site

I want to get only first 3 divs, in other words, I want to get all consecutive `div.row`.

This is code I am using

```
foreach (pq('h3:contains("Specifications")', $profile_page)->nextAll('div.row') as $div) {

}
```

But what it does, it also scrapes the `some text 4` div as well.

I have tried `nextAll('div.row')` as well but it gives me same result.

So my question is, how do I get all consecutive `div.row` after `<h3>Specifications</h3>`, if any other tag comes in between then just STOP.

PS:

Answers in pure jQuery will also be accepted, since phpQuery library uses same function as jQuyery does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:first` selector to get the first `.row` element, then `nextUntil()` to capture the rest. Try this:

```
var $rows = $('.row:first').nextUntil(':not(.row)');
```

If you want to also include the first row in the matched set you can use `addBack()`, like this:

```
var $rows = $('.row:first').nextUntil(':not(.row)').addBack();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/xxn3pqfg/)

Comment: sadly, there is no function `nextUntil` in phpQuery library ... :( is there any other thing I can do??? maybe a REGEX solution?

Comment: Actually i am doing web scrapping and this script will be running as a cronjob ... So i cant use jquery

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$("h3").nextUntil("#pricing");
```

Captures all the elements after `h3` until it reaches that with the id of `pricing`

Comment: this is not sure whether there will be a DIV with ID pricing ... I want to stop getting next div if any other tag comes in between there

Answer (score 0):

Consecutive divs, eh? It sounds like you want something like:

```
div.row:has(+ div.row),div.row + div.row
```

I don't know if PHPQuery supports that, if not you should consider switching.

Another idea is to do `h3 + .row` and then just keep iterating `+ .row`